# Howto sanitize inputs

Tags: java, input, sanitize, owasp, esapi

I am willing to use "OWASP ESAPI for Java" to sanitize users inputs when they submits forms in a Tomcat Webapp.

I used to use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` like this:

```
public static String myEscapeHtml(String s)
{
    String s_escapedString = null;       
    s_escapedString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s);
    return s_escapedString;
}
```

I don't know anymore if this is good enough to protect the webapp "reasonably"...

I would like to know what lines of code I should write to use the OWASP ESAPI to sanitize a Tomcat webapp user inputs.

Can you give an example in which one or several ESAPI "filters" (escaping?, encoding? ...) would be applied to a string to sanitize it?

The backend RDBMS is PostgreSQL.

The Tomcat server can either be be running on a Linux server or on a Windows server.

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: My original title was "Howto sanitize inputs using Owasp Esapi for Java". I think it's worth precising what library and programming language I would like to use in the title of the thread. But maybe, according to your standards, the tags are enough to have the thread be properly referenced... I hope I'll get an answer :)

Comment: Are you interested in input encoding or output encoding?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would say "output encoding" to avoid injections inside HTML code...

Answer (score 9):

For input validation, you'll use [`org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator`.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.java)

If you want to define your own validation rules in `validation.properties`, the technique to do that is demonstrated in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499820/error-when-using-esapi-validation/24535609#24535609).

For output escaping, that's actually quite easier.  Preferably when inserting data into an object that will be sent to the presentation layer, you'll want to use `String output = ESAPI.encoder().escapeForHTML(String s);` methods.

The full list of methods is defined in [`org.owasp.esapi.Encoder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.java#Encoder).

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://github.com/owasp/java-html-sanitizer/issues/15)

This sanitizes the input from HTML, and ensures quotes are kept.

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
HtmlSanitizer.Policy policy = myPolicyBuilder.build(new HtmlStreamEventReceiver() {
    public void openDocument() {}
    public void closeDocument() {}
    public void openTag(String elementName, List<String> attribs) {
        if ("br".equals(elementName)) { sb.append('\n'); }
    }
    public void closeTag(String elementName) {}
    public void text(String text) { sb.append(text); }
});
HtmlSanitizer.sanitize(myHtml, policy);
```