# Error when using Esapi validation

Tags: java, regex, validation, owasp, esapi

I hope someone could help me with some issue.

I'm using OWASP ESAPI 2.1.0 with JavaEE, to help me to validate some entries in a web application. At some point I needed to validate a Windows file path, so I added a new property entry in the 'validation.properties' like this one:

```
Validator.PathFile=^([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[\\w. -]+)+$
```

When I try to validate, for example, a string like "C:\TEMP\file.txt" via ESAPI, I get a ValidationException:

```
ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("PathFile", "C:\\TEMP\\file.txt", "PathFile", 100, false);
```

Alternatively, I also tried the *java.util.regex.Pattern* class to test the same regular expression with the same string example and it works OK:

```
Pattern.matches("^([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[\\w. -]+)+$", "C:\\TEMP\\file.txt")
```

I must say that I added other regex in 'validation.properties' and worked OK. Why this one is so hard? Could anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: Why are we being asked to validate Windows file paths?  What is the use case?

Comment: Hi, @avgvstvs , thanx a lot for you answer below. That file path is just a context parameter for my web application meant for writing a log file somewhere. Since that param should be written in the web.xml file by one of the administrators it wouldn't mean any intrusion into the application, but I wanted to use ESAPI validation anyway to check that the path is correctly formed. I didn't notice that getValidDirectoryPath method. I better off read the Validator doc carefully. Thanx again ;-)

Comment: I'm still points-hungry... so if you could, would you mark the answer as accepted, or at least upvote?  I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @avgvstvs, I've just accepted the answer (didn't know I could do that) but I'm not allowed to upvote anything yet, I have only 13 points!! I'm sorry! I'll do it as soon as I can, promise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the call to `validator().getValidInput("PathFile", "C:\\TEMP\\file.txt", "PathFile", 100, false);` wraps a call to `ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize()` that is transforming the input to the char sequence (Not literal `String`!) `C:TEMP'0x0C'ile.txt` before it passes to the regex engine.

Except for the second "\" getting converted to the `char 0x0c` this is normally desired behavior.  That could be a bug in ESAPI.

What you want, is to make a call to [ESAPI.validator().getValidDirectoryPath()](http://web.archive.org/web/20160313123526/http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html#getValidDirectoryPath%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29)